# I'm trying to install autogluon from sagemaker, but I keep getting errors

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

!pip install --upgrade mxnet-cu100

!pip install autogluon

The error continues to occur when the above two codes are executed in sagemaker studio.

```
Collecting seqeval<=1.2.2
  Using cached seqeval-1.2.2.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:126: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 4.0.0-unsupported is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
        PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
      /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-b9s5vfp9/seqeval_f21cd9e2f7e648ce8f203ea1e6d8ee59/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
          'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy'
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 86, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 80, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 877, in fetch_build_eggs
          replace_conflicting=True,
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
          replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1075, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1087, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 944, in fetch_build_egg
          return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 87, in fetch_build_egg
          wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 110, in install_as_egg
          self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 118, in _install_as_egg
          self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 170, in _convert_metadata
          extras_require=extras_require,
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 479, in __init__
          for k, v in attrs.items()
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 283, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 898, in finalize_options
          for ep in sorted(loaded, key=by_order):
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 897, in <lambda>
          loaded = map(lambda e: e.load(), filtered)
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 196, in load
          return functools.reduce(getattr, attrs, module)
      AttributeError: type object 'Distribution' has no attribute '_finalize_feature_opts'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

import autogluon as ag

from autogluon import TabularDataset as task

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-74ced3fb9150> in <module>
----> 1 import autogluon as ag
      2 from autogluon import TabularDataset as task

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autogluon'
```

There was an error during installation, so of course the module is not loaded. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: which kernel are you using I was able to successfully install and run it using mxnet kernel.